# Calculating the force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

We've just started with the topic "Forces in Mechanics" in Physics, so my knowledge so far regarding Forces is restricted to the three [Newton's axioms](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Newton%27s+Axioms).

I was given the following problem

> A $300g$ hammer with an initial speed of $4\frac{m}{s}$ hits a nail $5mm$ deep in the wood.
>
> Determinate the force $F_{H\to N}$ that the hammer exerts to the nail.

**My approach so far**

It is a well-known fact that $$F[N]=m[kg]·a\bigg[\frac{m}{s^2}\bigg]$$
Here we know that $m=0,3kg$ and that $v_{init}=4\frac{m}{s}$
. However, how should I determine the acceleration?

Any help is accepted;)

Comment: Start with the force that the nail applies to the hammer. It slows the hammer from 4 m/s to 0 within 5mm distance.

Comment: not relevant here but recently closed.... drawbridge sensor http://i.stack.imgur.com/MoPg8.png

Comment: Oh! Thanks @Sunnyskyguy EE75.

Comment: The force decays to 0. The initial force is F=Δp/Δt= mΔv/Δt= 0.3 * 4 / Δt,  assume Δt=0.1mm / 4 mm/ms = 25 us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the energy of hammer has turned into the work and moved the nail by 5mm into the wall.

Energy of the hammer is $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

And the work done by the force F is $W = F*x $

So there you go.

Comment: And shouldn’t we also consider the wall’s resistence? However this is not given...

Comment: No, it is not needed. You just equate E to W.

Comment: The problem statement is very ambiguous.

Comment: @DavidWhite, it is a very unambiguous question, a hammer with known mass and velocity has an inelastic collision with a nail. All the energy is used to drive the nail, no mention of hammer recoil, so the work w = F * displacement = F* 5mm is equal to kinetic energy of the hammer, ignoring the mass of nail.

Comment: @kamran, is the nail 5 mm deep when the hammer hits it?  Is the nail at the surface of the wood and the hammer drives it 5 mm deep?  Is the nail just starting in the wood and the hammer drives it 5 mm deep?  The different answers will tend to result in a different contact time and a different force.  And note - you answered about the kinetic energy of the nail ... the OP asked what force was involved.

Comment: @DavidWhite, say the nail is Di.mm embedded in the wall, after the impulse it penetrates 5mm more at Df.mm. So regardless of the initial embedment W = F (Di - Df) = F* 5mm..

Comment: @kamran, your answer gave the work involved, but you didn't answer the OP's question.  He asked how much force was involved, and force is not equal to work.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I feel you have not read my answere.-- Ke = F*x. can you calculate the F here or no, if not I give you the solution in a private message. we should not do the homework for OP.

Comment: @kamran, $F=\Delta p / \Delta t$, according to Newton's 2nd law.  How long does it take for the hammer to come to rest?

Answer (score 1):

I won't solve it for you but start with

[image: 1]

Comment: If you are going  to give a hint, I would at least state what assumptions go into this hint.

Comment: What did you have in mind?

Comment: Well I'll give you a hint :) What are you assuming by using energy conservation in a simple way here?